# Как правильно перестроить запрос в yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

как перестроить такой запрос под `findOne()`?

```
return static::find()
    ->where(['username' => $username])
    ->andWhere(['!=','status', self::STATUS_DELETED])
    ->one();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Давно не писал под Yii2, если не ошибаюсь, то можно было так:

```
return static::findOne([
    'username' => $username, 
    ['!=', 'status', self::STATUS_DELETED]
]);
```

**Update 1**

Подробнее можно посмотреть примеры в [официальной документации на github](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/db-active-record.md)

Comment: не воркает так.

Comment: @dasauser обновил ответ, попробуйте еще раз
P.S. к сожалению нет возможности сейчас проверить у себя

Comment: нет, все равно не работает. в оф. доках не нашел примеров с неравенством.